# Riak like REST service with Angular.js client

Tags: angularjs, rest, put, riak, riak-js

I used Riak(http://basho.com/riak/) as rest service and Angular on client. When I try to use method "PUT" then first request is OPTION, but Riak doesn't know how to properly respond for this.

I found some clients but all of them are made to run on server, not sure about Node.js client like this http://riak-js.org/
Can I make it working from web client?

Maybe Riak was not meant to work with web clients directly, then I'll try something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found js gui client for Riak https://github.com/basho/rekon, but it works directly from riak, that's not what i wanted but maybe i can use same solution also, or make proxy on server

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Riak, but the `OPTIONS` request suggests that you're trying to perform a cross-domain request (Angular running on domain *"aaa.com"*, Riak on domain *"bbb.com"*, although it can also even be just a different subdomain or port number).

My guess is that Riak doesn't support [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), in which case you need to look for an alternative (a simple server-side proxy might be all that you need, although please consider the security impact of exposing Riak directly to browsers).